# how to call another function just once from recursive function without using the static variable?

Tags: c++, c, recursion

This is a sample program for my problem, I am using VisualStudio 2008

```
void abc()
{
    static int i = 0;
    if (i==0)
    {
        xyz();
        i++;
    }
    abc();
}
```

The static variable retain the value one in next debug session also, thus not calling `xyz()`, how can I call a function just once without using static variable??

Comment: As stated the problem is ill posed. Just call the function once. Or return a value from the function that says "don't do this again".

Comment: Huh, what? Then just not make the variable `static`? Or do you then want the function to be called *repeatedly?* But you are asking for calling it *inly once*... this just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Believe me, you don't need static!!

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
void abc(int init)
{
    if(init == 1) xyz();
    abc(0);
}

int main(void) {
  abc(1);
}
```

It has the advantage of showing clearly what is going on. You could even declare an enum:

```
enum INIT {FIRST_TIME, RECURSING};
```

and do

```
void abc(enum INIT init) {
  if(init == FIRST_TIME) xyz();
  abc(RECURSING):
}
```

You can see a complete example at work at http://codepad.org/7euiC5LQ

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum INIT {FIRST, RECURSING};

void abc(enum INIT init) {
  if(init == FIRST) {
   printf("first time\n");
   abc(RECURSING);
  }
  else {
   printf("last time\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  abc(FIRST);
}
```

In this example, the second time is the last time. Obviously you can embellish from there; usually you will want to pass a parameter to your `abc` function that might decrease with each call until you reach some point that says "this is the end of the recursion" (think factorials, Fibonacci, etc). In that case, passing an "invalid" parameter (e.g. `-1`) for the initial call would be a good solution. You still have only one parameter.

Finally - when you are using C++, you could consider overloading your function. Call it with a parameter, and you include `xyz`; call it without, and you don't. A bit like the `abcStart` of one of the other answers. But since you tagged your question both C and C++, and there was no evidence in your code that you really intended C++, I am not even going there...

Comment: @GhrijeshChauhan thanks for catching the typo!

Comment: i have to call the function abc() from main() only, i am not calling it from abc itself,from main it is going to be called n times

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail What do you mean? Your own sample code shows you calling `abc` from itself, and you stated that it is a recursive function.

Comment: What @JBentley said... The whole point of recursion is that you call the function from within the function. And your own code calls `abc` from within `abc`. I am royally confused now.

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail "From main it is going to be called n times" - then it is not a recursive function, and what you're saying now flatly contradicts the content of your question.

Comment: @JBentley True,but i think i could have interpreted my problem in more better way, so can i achieve that also??

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail That is entirely possible, but you didn't ask us to judge whether you should use recursion vs a loop, you asked us how to call a function once from inside a recursive function. You need to post a separate question if you want to change track.

Comment: okey ..can u provide hint here itself

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail No, that is not how Stackoverflow works (and in any case we have no idea what your new requirements are). Post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you're looking for but it works

```
void abc(){
   abc();
}

void abcStart(){
   xyz();
   abc();
}

int main(){
   abcStart();
}
```

Doing this you don't need to specify any flag or use any `if`. You just call the "start" function of your recursion

Comment: Works for the sample program, but it will fail in real code if `xyz` needs to be called in the middle of `abc` instead of at the start.

Comment: @JBentley: You might have mentioned that in your question?

Comment: @quamrana It is not my question. However the OP did mention that it is sample code, and in any case it is obvious that it is not real code. The question asks in general terms how to call a function once from a recursive function - it doesn't specify that that function will be called at the start.

Comment: @JBentley: Sorry, my mistake.  Still, great answer from EoiFirst - so simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `callflag` to `abc()` function as an indication that whether to call `xyz()` function or not.

```
void abc(int callflag){
   // do somwork
   if(callflag)
      xyz();  // xyz() willbe called when callflag = !0
   // do other stuff
   abc(0)
}

void abcStart(){
  abc(1);
  //abc(0); If you don't want to call xzy even for first time. 
}
```

I think this is flexible call `xyz()` within `abc()` whenever you wants.

Comment: you don't need the `abc(0);` call in `abcStart()`

Comment: @quamrana I means that even if OP don't wants to call xyz even for first time. Although I have corrected thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Boolean variable in the caller and pass it to the called function.

```
#include <stdbool.h> // C99 and latter supports.  

void abc(bool flag)
{
    if (flag)
    {
        xyz();
        flag = false;
    }
    abc(flag);
}

int main(void)    // T is return type
{
    ...

    bool flag = true;
    abc(flag);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: @quamrana; Why it does't compile?

Comment: `abc();` should produce an error to do with the number of parameters.

Comment: @quamrana; That was typo. Fixed that.

Comment: Ok, better...  See answer from Grijesh

Comment: @quamrana; I can see. I just use `flag` variable which is of `booltype`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44419/discussion-between-quamrana-and-haccks)

Comment: Down voter care to explain. Do not just downvote because someone has downvoted it already. Better to read the answer.

Comment: That's twice you have `flag=false;` with no effect either time!

Comment: @quamrana; That's for the next time call of the function.

Comment: `main` should be calling `abc` with literal parameter.

Comment: @quamrana; Why it should? Since when it is wrong to use a variable as argument?

Comment: Its only wrong when the variable is not variable.

Comment: @quamrana; Could you elaborate it more?

Comment: This is silly - yes, it is neater to simply call `abc(true)` or `abc(false)`, but that doesn't make the answer wrong, or worth a downvote. I'm adding a +1

Comment: In your `main` you call `abc(flag);` which makes the code say that it doesn't know the value of `flag`, which is patently not the case.

Comment: @JBentley; You are right. At the time of answering I concentrated just on logic.

Comment: @quamrana; `In your main you call abc(flag); which makes the code say that it doesn't know the value of flag, which is patently not the case.`: This does't make sense to me to downvote an answer for such a reason. In spite of this, you are an experienced programmer and hope you have a good experience. May be you are right on your point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which doesn't hard code it to running `xyz` a single time i.e. you could later trivially change it to run it an arbitrary number of times (credit to Floris whose answer I adapted):

```
void abc(int i)
{
    if(i > 0)
        {
            xyz();
            i--;
        }
    abc(i);
}

int main()
{
    abc(1);
}
```