# How should we call a function just once from a function which is called 'n' no. of times from the main function without using static variable?

Tags: c

I am using vs 2008,This is a sample program for the problem i am facing

```
int main()
{
    abc();
    abc();
    abc();
    abc();
    return 0;
}

void abc()
{
    static int Val = 0;

    if(Val == 0)
    {
        xyz();
        val++;
    }

    printf("This is abc");
}

void xyz()
{
    printf("This is xyz");
}
```

This approach works fine for the first debug session,xyz() is called only once,but in the next debug session static variableVal  retains its value to one only so xyz() is not called at all,how can i call xyz() once without using static, as static is not at all helpful for my problem??

Comment: What do you mean by "next debug session"?  Restarting the program with a new debug session should cause `Val` to be reset to zero as well.

Comment: Do you mean that your static variable keeps its value between different debug sessions? *What*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call another function just once from recursive function without using the static variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904264/how-to-call-another-function-just-once-from-recursive-function-without-using-the)

Comment: Since I don't see `Val` ever being changed it seems `xyz` would be called every time.  You could pass a parameter to the function to decide what to do inside it, but I think it would be better if you explained why you want this behavior if you want the best solution.

Comment: Yes static variable is retainging its value,actually its just a sample for my problem,my program uses httpd service attached for the debug session,and its retaining static variable value in next session also,so how can we achieve it without static?

Comment: If you post the real code you'll likely get real help.  If you want a variable to persist between sessions save and load it.

Comment: Dont mark it as duplicate,it is completely different from that Question if u observe

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail the only difference is the recursion, which was irrelevant anyway. If the *real* question is something like "why doesn't my debug session reset the original state" then ask *that* question.

Comment: So your process keeps running, and you need the function to be called 'once in something', and only you know what the something is (is it attaching a debugger? a new HTTP session? some other event?). Anyway. Make the `Val` global and reset it each time your 'something' happens.

Comment: Yes @Inspired it should reset by itself,how can i reset it?

Comment: Nothing happens by itself. You should write code resetting it into some part of your program that is called upon beginning (or terminating) of your 'something'.

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail: no one can tell you how to reset it until you explain what the situation really is.  For example, if it's an HTTP server and you need to have it reset for each client session, then how to reset it will depend on how client sessions are represented and how the program is notified of the creation of sessions.  You apparently have a more complex scenario than needing to reset a variable when the program is restarted. You'll need to tell us more about your actual situation.

Comment: okey,so how can we write that @ inspired??

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail Ok, I'll tell you: just write `Val = 0;`. Where? *Somewhere.* No one knows except you. Your program should receive some notifications to be able to do that in appropriate time.

Comment: Generally, I'd go the way @Inspired already wrote. I'd additionally suggest to use a (global) Functor, that internally keeps its state. Then you can add a `reset` method or similar on your Functor to reset it. If you need this on a per-connection basis or similar, better create one Functor per connection, so you don't need to reset manually

Comment: @MichaelBurr, i am calling ap_log_perror from my main function,internally it calls two other functions before going to ap_log_perror definition,from ap_log_perrorfn definition i call textfileread() fn, that reads the loglevel from config file,the textfileread function is written by me and included in their log.c implementation , i am not getting the condition so that loglevel is read just once and textfileread gets called eachtime i call ap_log_perror, before debug i need to attach it with httpd service,and next time static variable retains its value so can i have so that it get called once

Comment: @user1781290 i am working on a c code ,can i create a functor there, if yes how? please give example

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail Please do not tag your question C++ if it is about C, otherwise you mislead people trying to write answers. I have edited out your C++ tag.

Comment: You tagged `c++` aswell, so I thought this might be an option for you. It is not possible to write Functors in `c` as far as I know

Comment: @JBentley, okey, so any solutions for the my question??

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail You have been provided with three different solutions already - all will work, each with pros/cons.

Answer (score 2):

I would pass parameter instead of `static int` to be reentrant.
then caller can decide to reinit the state when desired.

```
int main()
{
    int state = 0;

    abc(&state);
    abc(&state);
    abc(&state);
    abc(&state);
    return 0;
}

void abc(int* state)
{
    if (*state == 0)
    {
        xyz();
        ++*state;
    }
    printf("This is abc");
}
```

Comment: +1 for a solution which solves the problem, although I prefer David Kernin's solution as the caller of `abc` doesn't have to worry about `state`.

Comment: @JBentley :The David's answer is correct for C++, but now the question is tagged only `C`. (And it is easy to add a method `reset` for David's solution).

Comment: Yes, that is true. I took out the C++ tag after the OP commented that his code is C.

Answer (score 1):

Controlling whether a function has been called or not in the same execution might be done in a way similar to the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct mySingletonFunction
{
    int first_time;
} mySingletonFunction;

void abc(mySingletonFunction *obj)
{
    if(!obj->first_time)
    {
        printf("Skipping..");
        return;
    }
    else
        obj->first_time = 0;

    printf("This is abc");
}

mySingletonFunction *initializeObject()
{
    mySingletonFunction *obj = (struct mySingletonFunction*)malloc(sizeof(struct mySingletonFunction));

    obj->first_time = 1;

    return obj; 
}

void callAbc(mySingletonFunction *obj)
{
    obj->first_time = 1;
}

void resetObject(mySingletonFunction *obj)
{
    obj->first_time = 1;
}

void deleteObject(mySingletonFunction *obj)
{
    free(obj);
}


int main()
{
    mySingletonFunction *myObject = initializeObject();

    abc(myObject);
    abc(myObject);
    abc(myObject);
    abc(myObject);
    abc(myObject);

    resetObject(myObject);

    abc(myObject);
    abc(myObject);
    abc(myObject);
    abc(myObject);
    abc(myObject);

    deleteObject(myObject);

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/tSzF7v

Although there are many other ways to do it. I didn't quite understand what you mean with "next debug session" though.

Comment: IMO the best solution so far, since the caller of `abc` doesn't have to worry about whether it is being called for the first time or not.

Comment: Given that the OP apparently has an issue with the "first time" flag persisting between "sessions" (whatever that means), it's probably worth adding some kind of reset function to `mySingletonFunction` which reverts `xyz_first_time` back to `true`, which can be called in between sessions as needed.

Comment: I agree, although destroying the object and creating a new one would suffice to reset the thing. I'm not sure of what OP wants either.

Comment: session just means that another time, my question states that my static variable initialized to one in first iteration of the program, retains value one during second iteration or third iteration of program also, and i am working on c so i cant destroy the object,any new solutions

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail Then use Jarod42's answer, and modify his `state` variable in between iterations of your program. You've been asked repeatedly what is preventing you from doing this (or similar) and have failed to address this point. Also, don't waste people's time - you tagged the question C++ and DavidKernin took the time to provide a C++ solution.

Comment: Although you have no objects you can implement the same thing with a structure, sorry for not having seen the C tag earlier. A static variable will retain its value for the entire duration of the program. I modified my answer to help in this case

Comment: Yeah,Jarod answer would be fine..

Comment: I included some C code which implements an internal state. Take a look at it, it may be useful somehow

Answer (score 0):

Make the val variable global and increment the val variable inside abc()

Comment: Although that is an alternative I don't think recommending a global is a good idea.

Comment: For global also its retaining value,tell me some other approach

Comment: I think you may have some other problem as global can be an alternative.

Comment: @D.A.Danekhail Nobody knows what you mean by "it's retaining value". If you don't want "it" to retain the value, then you need to write code to reset the value when your "session" ends. Several people have already made similar comments on your question.